# Can't use FB Authentication in IE

Tags: javascript, facebook, perl, authentication, sdk

I am trying to use the FB Javascript SDK to authenticate users on my website.  The login button refuses to appear on any version of IE that I have. It appears on Opera, Safari, etc.

Does anyone know the answer to this?

Also, a rather broad question:  I am a Perl programmer and would prefer if it's easier to do this via Perl, but if I can't, I can't.

Comment: Can you show the code you are using which doesn't work in IE?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure it is possible to put your own login buttons up.

Just worth checking - I suffered from the login button not working in early versions of IE (7+8). I found the javascript listener event caused me problems and changing the listener event to an onclick event fixed login for me.

The fact it works in other browsers, means your code is probably ok, but double check that if you are embedding the HTML in perl, check that all $ signs in JQuery are backslashed (eg \$) otherwise they will disappear when rendered and it will fail. Just check the source code matches your perl embedded code.

Otherwise can you supply some code or a link to the page?